# Help with complicated functional equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, contest-math, functional-equations

> **Problem:** Let $T=\{(p,q,r)\mid p,q,r \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq0}\}$. Find all functions $f:T\to \mathbb{R}$ such that:
>   $$f(p,q,r)=\\ 
> =\begin{cases}
> 0, & \text{ if } pqr = 0 \\ 
> 1 + \frac{1}{6}\left(f(p+1,q-1,r)+f(p+1,q,r-1)+f(p,q+1,r-1)+\\
> \;\;\;\;\;\;
> f(p,q-1,r+1)+f(p-1,q+1,r)+f(p-1,q,r+1)\right) & \text{ otherwise.} 
> \end{cases}$$

**Progress so far:** It's not hard to see that $f$ is symmetric in $p,q,r$, which is useful to know. From the recursive definition one can also infer that $f:T\to \Bbb{Q}^+$, so no trig functions or logs. That's all I could observe from the get-go. I've tried calculating some values of $f$ to have an idea on how the functions look like (if there are any) but having trouble calculating even small values of $f$, for example $f(1,2,3)$ or $f(2,2,2)$. All I know is that $f(0,a,b)=0$ and $f(1,1,1)=1$. I could guess a solution based on my initial observations but I can't see any obvious candidates.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: $\displaystyle\;f(p,q,r) = \frac{3pqr}{p+q+r}\;$ is a solution. I believe this is the only solution but I can't prove it.

Comment: How did you get this solution?

Comment: If you look at your equation, $(p,q,r)$ only connects to points with same $p+q+r$. This means you can look at each $p+q+r = \text{constant}$ layer separately. The intersection of $T$ with any such layer forms a triangular lattice. Your equation reduces to a discrete version of Poisson equation there. The boundary condition suggest the solution (at least in continuum limit) contains a factor proportional to $pqr$. Direct substitution shows that you can scale this to get a solution. Since we are dealing with some sort of "Poisson equation", that's why I suspect the solution is unique.

Comment: This is an IMO 2001 shortlist problem.

Comment: Thank you, Calvin. I found this problem  some lecture notes so I didn't know where it came from. Ironically, I looked up the solution on AoPS just to find out that they pulled out of nowhere the function Achille discovered and then proved that this is the only solution.

Comment: So formally the problem is solved but I'm still not quite satisfied. I'm really curious about how to come up with the function. @achillehui: I don't understand your method (I've never studied this), but I'm really interested in it. Could you recommend some material where I can learn about those techniques, or at least tell me what subject it is. Is it from differential equations?

Comment: @DeathkampDrone There isn't a central place to learn this sort of tricks. When you attack a problem, you should pay attention to whether it looks like other problems (no matter how remote it sounds) you have deal with before. To me, this problem looks like some electrostatic problem I have seen before. So I use what I know in those electrostatic problems, draw analogies and make educational guesses.

Comment: I see, thanks for the advice! I'll leave the question open for a few more days before the bounty expires in case someone comes up with a simpler way of getting that function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I worked on this problem back in 2002, showing uniqueness was really easy through the "average of neighbors" observation (albeit on a slanted hexagonal board, instead of the regular chessboard).

**Proof of uniqueness:** Suppose we have 2 solutions $ f(p,q,r)$ and $ g(p,q,r)$. Let $ h(p,q,r) = f(p,q,r) - g(p,q,r)$. Then, we get that

$$ 6 h(p,q,r) = h(p+1, q-1, r) + h(p-1, q+1, r) + h( p, q+1, r-1) + h( p, q-1, r+1) + h( p+1, q, r-1) + h(p-1, q, r+1). $$

Consider the plane $ p+q+r = N$. Oberve that the neighbors of the cell $(p,q,r)$ are these 6 other cells with coordinates as given above. Hence, every cell is the average of it's neighbors. Through the standard argument (extremal principle), this implies that all cells on this finite board are equal.

We also have the boundary conditions that $h(p,q,r ) = 0$ for $pqr=0$, hence $h(p,q,r) = 0$. Thus, the function is unique $_\square$

Finding the solution was harder, but still motivated from the conditions.
Note: It is important to bear in mind that as an ('easy') Olympiad problem, it often has a nice solution that can be motivated.

**Finding function:** From the boundary condition that $pqr=0 \Rightarrow f(p,q,r) = 0$, we guess the initial function $ F( p,q,r) = pqr$.

Observe that since $ (p-1)(q+1) r + (p+1)(q-1)r = 2pqr - 2r$, so this guess gives us:

$ F(p,q,r) = \frac{ p+q+r} { 3} + \frac{1}{6} [ F(p-1, q+1, r) + F(p+1, q-1, r) + F(p, q-1, r+1), F(p, q+1, r-1) + F( p-1, q, r+1), F(p+1, q, r-1) ] $.

Observe that since $p+q+r$ is a constant for all of these 7 terms, we should look at 
$$ f(p,q,r) = \frac{ F(p,q,r) } { \frac{p+q+r} {3} } = \frac{3 pqr} { p+q+r}.$$

Indeed, this works. $_\square$

Note: Had $F(p,q,r) = pqr$ not worked, the next guess would have been $ F(p,q,r) = p^2q^2r^2$

Answer (score 3):

Achille Hui did the hardest part of the work by discovering
the closed formula $\frac{3pqr}{p+q+r}$. The rest is a routine "maximum
principle" argument that I explain below.

For a positive integer $k$, let $T_k$ be the finite set
$\lbrace (p,q,r)\in T | p+q+r=k\rbrace$. For $x=(p,q,r)\in T$, define
the **neighborhood** $N(x)$ of $x$ to be

$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
N(p,q,r)&=&\lbrace (p+1,q-1,r);(p+1,q,r-1);(p,q+1,r-1); \\
& & (p,q-1,r+1);(p-1,q+1,r);(p-1,q,r+1)\rbrace
\end{array}
\tag{1}
$$

and the **strict neighborhood** $N'(x)$  of  $x$ to be 
$\lbrace (u,v,w)\in N(x) | uvw>0\rbrace$. We say that $x\in T_k$ is **interior**
if $N’(x)=N(x)$, and **extremal** otherwise.

Let $g(p,q,r)=f(p,q,r)-\frac{3pqr}{p+q+r}$ for $(p,q,r)\in T$. Then $g$ satisfies
$g(p,q,r)=0$ if $pqr=0$, and

$$
6g(x)=\sum_{y\in N'(x)}g(y) \tag{2}
$$

for any $x\in T_k$ (note that $N(x)$ and $N’(x)$ stay in $T_k$ when $x\in T_k$).

Now, let $M$ ($m$) be the maximum (minimum) value of $g$ on $T_k$. There is
some $x_M\in T_k$ such that $g(x_M)=M$. We now apply (2) to $x=x_M$, and obtain
a formula (2').

If $M > 0$, then (2') is only possible when $x_M$ is interior and $g(y)=M$
for all $y\in N(x_M)$. If we put $L=\lbrace x\in T_k | g(x)=M\rbrace$, we would deduce
that $L$ consists only of interior points but also satisfies
$N(x)\subseteq L$ for any $x\in L$, which is impossible because when we move away from the interior of $T_k$ we are always forced to eventually reach extremal points.

So $M\leq 0$. A similar argument (or if you please, you may reuse
the result just shown on $-g$ instead of $g$) shows that $m\geq 0$.

So $M\leq 0 \leq m$, but on the other hand $m\leq M$. This forces
$m=M=0$, so $g$ is identically zero.

To conclude, $\frac{3pqr}{p+q+r}$ is the unique solution.